# Ho can i return a Custom HTML div in React JS?

Tags: html, reactjs

my purpose is to render a div that i have already created by createElement .

And I have a did that into a ReactJs function so i need to return the div but doing it like that doesn't work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class main extends Component {
renderList() {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
                  div.appendChild(ul);
                return div
            }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this.renderList()} 
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default main;
```

It gave me this error but when i did **console.log(div)** I do get

```
     <div>......</div>
```

> react-dom.development.js:2317 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can I achieve that ? thnx

Comment: Your code really does not help to reproduce the problem you describe. With that said: in React _usually_ you do not create elements directly with `createElement()`. If you have one (there are a FEW cases) then you should use a portal to render React code inside it. My gut feeling is: drop HTML DOM manipulation and write React code.

Comment: How do you use `renderList()`? If it is like `{ renderList() }` then most probably you need to return from that function a valid **JSX**.

Comment: Where/how are you using this in React?  And why are you using `document.createElement` instead of just using React components?

Comment: I have to use createElement because i am building according to an algorithm  either <ul> or <li> . I have edited

Comment: @suuuustt: The real solution here is *probably* to use React components as they're intended to be used.  The code in the question doesn't really demonstrate why you can't.  Just use JSX elements like you're already using in `render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For futur readers, for a better approach, don't use this answer... (see first comment)

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as your way is dangerous

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class main extends Component {
    renderList() {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
                  div.appendChild(ul);
                return div.outerHTML;
            }

    render() {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.renderList()}} />
        );
    }
}


export default main;
```

---

As said, you should privilege the react way. In something like this.

```
getList() {
    return (
       <ul>
         {aCustomArrayOfLi.map(aLi => (
              <li>{aLi}</li>
          ))}
       </ul>
    );
}

render() {
    <div>
       {this.getList()}
    </div>

}
```

Comment: As mentionned, it's dangerously, even if you think your way is better, it's the worst...

Comment: Thank u Patrick actually this is the solution and as you said it works but in dangerous way so i will look how can i use the safe way

Comment: @suuuustt, here is an exemple, if you can provide a context, any variable, a better exemple could be provided.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you try this way ?  I think   instead of  ,

Create your renderList as react functional component and import your main extends class.

```
import React from 'react'

export const RenderList= () => 
{

 return (

        <div> 
            <ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )}
```

Your Main Class

```
import {RenderList} from 'RenderList'

    class main extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  <RenderList/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }



export default main;
```

Comment: u have right thank uu i will try to make it possible to work like that